# How does asynchronous request work for server side validation

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, xmlhttprequest

How can I asynchronously validate against a database for a value in form field?

For e.g. I have a text-box where users enter an userID to check if its available or not, I want check the input against a database table asynchronously without refreshing the page. How can I make this happen?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [`[Remote]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Comment: Sorry for misinformation(wrong tag). Its not an MVC application, its a standard web application. I dont think [Remote] attribute is available for standard web app.

Comment: @user793468, if it's not an ASP.NET MVC application why is your question tagged with `asp.net-mvc`? Anyway, if it is not an ASP.NET MVC application you could directly use the [jquery.validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and the [remote](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options) rule.